# Android and iOS tasks on Targetprocess

Tags: android, ios, targetprocess

I have the following question:

I have one team using two OS: Android and iOS. Each time the requirements for both are merged into a single task.

I am using Targetprocess as visual tool for PM. At the moment there is no problem using a single user story/task for both OS. Hence, there is feedback we receive from the client and always this feedback reflects different tasks from both iOS and Android. I want to record them on Targetprocess and I want to ask if anybody has faced that issue before?

P.S. Whenever, there is a feedback for iOS and Android, the status of the single task will not be correct because for iOS it could be "in testing", and for Android it could be "done" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the 2 approaches below:

1. Create 2 User Stories (one for iOS and one for Android) under the same Feature. Thus, requirements will be listed in Feature description, while you will move User Stories between states separately.
2. Create identical stories for different OSs, and link them using the Relations mechanism. https://www.targetprocess.com/guide/working-with-entities/relations/relations-management/